# notation for subspaces in multi-dimensional rooms

Tags: vector-spaces

Is there a proper notation for denoting subspaces in multi-dimensional space?

For example how can add in the notation $U \subseteq V$ that $V \in \mathbb{R}^\ell$. Is there is a proper/compact/elegant notation?

Comment: Your notation does not compile. Maybe you meant $V \subseteq \Bbb R^\ell$?

Comment: Assuming you mean $\subseteq$ instead of $\in$, why not just write $U\subseteq V\subseteq\mathbb R^{\ell}$?

Comment: I think you mean "multi-dimensional spaces", not "rooms".  Also "$V\in R^l$ is not good notation.  $R^l$ is itself a vector space not a collection of vector spaces.  You probably mean that $V= R^l$.  There is no special notation, as far as I know, for "subspace".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.... I meant "multi-dimensinoal space" yes. Let me put in words what I want to write down mathematically. I have a data set, composed by real numbers, lying in a multi-dimensional space. Further, I want to refer to a specific sub-set of that data. All of this, denoting that my data is in a multi-dimentional space, and so the sub-set.